# Dynamic namespace mapping in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

```
I Have a requirement to do a transformation mapping for input xml for which the namespace can change in future.

If I define my input XML with namespace: xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.sample.com.au/emprec/v1

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap:Body>
                <ns1:EmpRecord xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.sample.com.au/emprec/v1">
                        <ns1:firstname>firstname</ns1:firstname>
                        <ns1:lastname>lastname</ns1:lastname>
                        <ns1:address>
                            <ns1:unit>1</n1:unit>
                            <ns1:street>st</ns1:street>
                            <ns1:suburb>suburb</ns1:suburb>
                        </ns1:address>
        </ns1:EmpRecord>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

and my XSLT as

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xp20="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.Xpath20"
                xmlns:oraext="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.ExtFunc"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.sample.com.au/emprec/v1"
                xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.sample.com.au/transformtotarget/v1"
                xmlns:ora="http://schemas.oracle.com/xpath/extension"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xsi xsl xsd wsdl ns1 xp20">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ns2:EMPLOYEES>
      <ns2:firstname>
        <xsl:value-of select="/ns1:EmpRecord/ns1:firstname"/>
      </ns2:firstname>
      <ns2:suburb>
         <xsl:value-of select="/ns1:EmpRecord/ns1:address/ns1:suburb"/>
      </ns2:suburb>
    </ns1:EMPLOYEES>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Above XSLT works fine as long as the namespace for XML is http://xmlns.sample.com.au/emprec/v1
How can I use the same xslt if my namespace at source change in future? 
lets say to: http://xmlns.sample.com.au/emprec/v2

I do not want to prefix namespace while mapping in xpath, i want it to be dynamic. 
I have tried to use local-name() function and it works , but not sure what's the performance impact if i have large payloads

```
  <ns2:suburb>
         <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='EmpRecord'/*[local-name()='address'/*[local-name()='suburb'"/>
      </ns2:suburb>
```

The above mapping works fine, but if my xpath is long will this be recommened approach in terms of performace and is there any better way to achieve this?

Please help.

Comment: What will you do if they change `<EmpRecord>` to `<Employee>`?

Comment: Element names are unlikely to change in my current scenario. The reason for namespace change is beacuse of new version of schema/xml.

Comment: A new version of schema is a different schema. Normally, a stylesheet transforms from one given schema to another. My point is that there are limits to future-proofing.

Comment: I agree, just trying to findout if there is a way to achive this as I have got so many xslt's which are designed and mapped to v1 namespace and now they have to cater for v2 and any future versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The namespace can change in future": the accepted wisdom is that that's not a good policy. Changing namespaces is highly disruptive and the costs of doing so almost always outweigh the benefits. So people end up not doing it, even if they originally intended to. (I don't know why W3C puts a year in its namespace URIs. Probably someone intended at the time that it would make it easier to change. But it doesn't, and instead these namespaces live for ever, frozen in time.)

My advice if you want to write a stylesheet that handles several input vocabularies (your problem is a special case of this) is to write a preprocessing phase for each vocabulary that normalizes the XML to use a single vocabulary. Then rather than having to handle the variations everywhere throughout your code, you do this job in one module and can write the "real" transformation without worrying about this extra problem.

You ask about performance without convincing us that it's critical. Maintainability of your code is usually much more important. But since you ask: performance depends on the products you are using. If you are using Saxon, then searching for a name that appears statically in your path expressions is MUCH more efficient than searching for names supplied dynamically as strings.

Comment: Hi Michaeal, Thank you for the excellent post. I have managed to convince the solution team to freeze the namespace. I am in sameline with you to have a pre-processing phjase to convert each vocabulary into one common data format which can then handle transformation requirements for target systems separately.Thankyou very much for the time you have taken to put up this comments here.

Answer (score 0):

Performance will depend upon the details of how the XSLT engine you're using was implemented, but the approach of using * and then adding a predicate to qualify it by local-name() is the best that XSLT and XPath 1.0 will give you.

The 2.0 version of the specs allows partial wildcards of prefix:* and *:localname.

However, the namespace name (the URI) really should not be at significant risk of "changing at the source in the future". That's part of the definition of the kind of document you're processing. Changing that makes it a different kind of document.

Comment: I agree, changing the namespace makes it different document. The whole thing comes down to workflow task which can accept any payload type of any namespace.

Comment: If it can accept any payload in any namespace, you shouldn't have to _change_ the namespace. You're throwing away meaningful data. Please reconsider your design.

Comment: With the usage of wildcards (*), I have tried that approach but the output i get is something like this:

Comment: <suburb>firstname lastname 1 st suburb</suburb>

Comment: It just picks up everything under emprecord, it just doesn't navigate to to the xpath ignoring the namespace

Comment: What happens when someone uses '<EmployeeRecord>' or otherwise changes the localname? That's precisely as likely as that someone will change the namespace.

If it's a different kind of document, all bets about its structure and meaning are off. Unless you're going to process it as pure XML, with semantics applied elsewhere, there really is not anything reasonable you can do here. The question is badly formed. [Mu.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative))

Comment: I accept with what you say, but if you are not sure what namespace you are going to get, how do we map? That is the reason I don't want to use anynamespace prefix in my xslt.

Comment: If you don't know what kind of document you're going to get, what do you map _to_?

Comment: Unlikely to change the localnames in this situation. change in namespace happens when there is a major change in schema version which the xml is tied to(lets says a new mandatory element added).

Comment: No, namespace should NOT change in that case. If it does, someone's misusing namespaces. Remember, the namespace is not the URI of the schema. (Or if it is, that's a historical accident of the first version of the schema and they'll diverge if the schema is revised.)

Answer (score -1):

If I had multiple stylesheets using a given namespace, and someone beyond my control had forced upon me a change of that namespace, I would open a text editor and perform a batch find/replace on all my stylesheets using that namespace (after backing them up first, of course). This is a one-time operation and once it's done you can get back to normal without worrying about continuous performance impact.